# Target src/main.rs::main()?

Tags: rust

I'm basically wondering what the optimal method for returning to the top of `src/main.rs::main()` is?

Maybe something like this:

```
mod main;

pub fn main() {
    crate::main();
}
```

Or maybe there's a keyword built in?

I want to handle certain kinds of errors by 'restarting the program'.

Comment: generally people use a loop

Comment: @Stargateur Yes, I thought people might do something using returns and breaks (so some kind of loop), but I don't know how to reference it (for example should I search for "main loop"?  What kind of book would I find this info in (like an algorithms book, or a basic programming patterns book)?  I'm trying to break into programming, and I feel like I'm puzzling through every little thing like this after having finished reading the primer and going through its examples: just putting the pieces together is a much bigger challenge.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of way, I advice the simple one, use a loop:

```rust
enum Error {
    A,
}

fn run() -> Result<(), Error> {
    if rand::random() {
        Ok(())
    } else {
        Err(Error::A)
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    while let Err(_) = run() {
        println!("Hello");
    }
}
```

However, be sure the program end maybe add a maximum fail counter.

Comment: Thanks.  I feel the program can end because: if a module fails in a specific way, I hope it returns to main.  Picture a game where if you die at a specific time/place, you go back to the main menu.  There are ways to succeed and ways to die that don't cause you to go back to the main menu (like find a save point).